# Select each item in dropdown list using Watin

Tags: c#, watin

I want to iterate through a dropdown list using Watin. The HTML looks like this:

```
<select name="ctl00$Header1$ddlPropertyList" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$Header1$ddlPropertyList\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_Header1_ddlPropertyList" onmouseover="this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title" style="width:325px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="0185795046:R:GPC:Eligible:F" title="0185795046 - ">0185795046 - </option>
    <option value="0325844068:R:GPC:Eligible:F" title="0325844068 - ">0325844068 - </option>
    <option value="0374795034:R:GPC:Eligible:F" title="0374795034 - ">0374795034 - </option>
    <option value="0510031035:C:GPC:Eligible:F" title="0510031035 - ">0510031035 - </option>
    <option value="1424795158:R:GPC:InEligible:F" title="1424795158 - ">1424795158 - </option>
    <option value="1550795037:R:GPC:Eligible:F" title="1550795037 - ">1550795037 - </option>

</select>
```

When you click on one of the options in the dropdown, it loads a different page, and I want to load each of them in succession. Basically, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SelectList ddl = browser.SelectList(Find.ById("ctl00$Header1$ddlPropertyList"));
            foreach (var item in ddl.AllContents)
            {
                ddl.Select(item);
            }
```

But I'm pretty sure my code is just wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you need to be on the page when you selecting the option in this case you need to return back on each select use the GoBack command after each select.

Comment: Yes, I am planning on selecting option 1 which will load a new page, but will still include the dropdown. I may or may not leave the page at that point, but I am planning on coming back to a page with the dropdown to select option 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looping through a list of items, sometimes I've run into cases where objects are out of scope, especially when using the Page Object pattern (use it - it is great!).  So I tend to use looping an explicitly declared count rather than referencing the list to loop through.  Added bonus:  Storing count in a variable and using that variable is quicker than referencing the browser object each time; makes a difference if you have a large number of items to loop through.

Some rough unfinished code - basically what alonp said fleshed out a bit more:

```
int numberOfItems = browser.SelectList(Find.ById("ctl00$Header1$ddlPropertyList")).count;

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
{
    //this is one the "search" page
    browser.SelectList(Find.ById("ctl00$Header1$ddlPropertyList")).Options[i].Select;
    browser.yourGoAction();   <- assumes navigation isn't automatic when an item is selected.  EG:  button.Click() or something.

    //this is on the "results" page.
    do stuff

    //go back to the "search" page.
    browser.Back();
}
```